# Error during update 'Unable to connect to 192.168.43.1:8000'

Tags: networking, upgrade, apt, updates

When I tried to update my Ubuntu through the update manager I received an error about some unknown resource. so i tried doing it from the terminal with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

but all I got is:

```
0% [Connecting to 192.168.43.1
```

repeating itself... and when I press Enter it shows:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 192.168.43.1:8000:

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Do u have INTERNET. Open firefox and see?

Comment: see what? ive been trying to find an answer for two days.... all i got is that it might bu cused by some mobile network wich i dont use...

Comment: This definitely looks like a network or proxy issue. 192.168.43.1 is _not_ a public Ubuntu repository (addresses beginning 192.168 are private network addresses behind people's routers, it could be your one of your own computers). Can you `ping archive.ubuntu.com`? If so, from the output of ping what address does it give you? Have you set up proxies anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `apt` is configured to use a proxy since `192.168.*.*` is a private IP range.

Use the next command to list all files in `/etc/apt` that contains `192.168.43.1`:

```
grep -rlF 192.168.43.1 /etc/apt
```

It possibly prints `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. Open that file. Find a line that contains the proxy configuration and remove it:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://192.168.43.1:8000/";
```

Save it and try updating again:

```
sudo apt-get update
```